# SQL Not In query working in Access but not MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to get this `SQL` query to work. It works in Access but not in `MySQL` giving me the error

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

Can anyone see what I have wrong? Is `Not In` not allowed?

My first query is

```
SELECT departments.personName FROM departments WHERE departments.departmentName='HR';
```

This is then embedded into the next query

```
SELECT DISTINCT allstaff.personName FROM allstaff
WHERE allstaff.personName Not In 
(SELECT departments.personName FROM departments WHERE departments.departmentName='HR';);
```

Comment: **WHERE'S THE REST OF YOUR ERROR MESSAGE**

Comment: Thanks but the others didn't need it. Point noted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of your query substitute `;);` with `);`

Comment: Fantastic - so simple. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove Semicolon (;)

Try like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT allstaff.personName FROM allstaff
WHERE allstaff.personName Not In 
(SELECT departments.personName FROM departments WHERE departments.departmentName='HR');
```

Comment: Thanks - such a small thing creating such a huge headache